# Error connecting MailChimp and Magento 1.9.3 using Magento Connect Manager

Tags: extensions, magento1.9.3, magento-connect-manager, mailchimp

I'm having trouble connecting my MailChimp account to my Magento database and I cannot find a fix on the forums. I'm hoping you can help.

I've obtained the access key for Magento 1.9.3 (Community Edition) and pasted the access key into the Magento Connect Manager. I did do this with the store in maintenance mode, disabled the compiler and flushed and disabled the cache. The
extension is still not pulling through and it's Magento is giving me the following error:
[image]

I have tried to change the Magento Connect Channel Protocol settings from HTTP to FTP (as recommended in another post), however, there is no option for FTP, just HTTPS and HTTP. Now, I'm at a bit of a dead end.

Can anyone suggest another path forward?

Many thanks
Annalisa

Comment: What is the mailchimp url you are using for extension key?

Comment: Not sure about this error, but you can download the plug-in here: https://github.com/mailchimp/mc-magento and upload it via FTP.

Comment: Thanks both. I have almost managed to do it using the FTP option rather than the Magento Connect Manager. Still having some issues but making progress.